# Breaking dotnet build doesn't break azure pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are trying to implement a full break on warning policy for our projects. To get the analyzer problems to fully propagate to errors only in release we used this in the csproj:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>True</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
      <MSBuildTreatWarningsAsErrors>true</MSBuildTreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

This works and the problems the analyzers finds are now treated as Errors. This is the ending output of the task "dotnet build" log.

```
13 Warning(s)
5 Error(s)
```

My problem is that the dotnet build task still treats this as a succesfull build, it's green and just continues on...

It even lists the errors in Azure Devops, but refuses to break.

[image: Listed errors and green result]

The task looks like this:
[image: fddd]

Comment: Could you try also with the argument `-warnaserror` during your task run? I am not sure how you should use it, maybe `-p:warnaserror` . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings

Comment: Ah, should have mentioned why that isn't an option. We have other projects, that are compiled in, that have a lot of warnings. That's why we have to be able to do it on a per project basis.